# How to write unicode strings into a file?

Tags: python, unicode

I am using python 2.6.5
I want to write some japanese characters to a file.
I am getting this error & I don't know how to change the encoding.

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Jun 12 2010, 17:07:01)
[GCC 4.3.4 20090804 (release) 1] on cygwin
>>> s = u'\u5E73\u621015'
>>> with open("yop", "wb") as f:
...   f.write( s + "\n" );
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: 
  ordinal not in range(128)
>>> type( s )
<type 'unicode'>
```

Answer (score 85, accepted):

you're going to have to 'encode' the unicode string.

```
s = u'\u5E73\u621015'
with open("yop", "wb") as f:
   f.write(s.encode("UTF-8"))
```

try this out for a bit of a friendly look at unicode and python: http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/

Comment: Is there a way to write real unicode characters like Danish language in the text file? I mean I don't want it to look like this "\u5E73" in the file. I want it to look like real character inside the file.

Answer (score 76):

As an alternative, you can use the `codecs` module:

```
import codecs
s = u'\u5E73\u621015'
with codecs.open("yop", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(s)
```

Answer (score 12):

The [codecs.open()](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) function in 2.6 is very similar to the built-in [open()](http://docs.python.org/release/3.3.0/library/functions.html#open) function in python3.x (which makes sense since Py3k strings are *always* Unicode). For future proofing your code in case it is used under Py3k you could do the following.

```
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import codecs
    _open_func_bak = open # Make a back up, just in case
    open = codecs.open

with open('myfile', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(u'\u5E73\u621015')
```

Now your code should work the same in both 2.x and 3.3+.

Answer (score 5):

Inserting this at the beginning of my script tends to solve unicode problems.

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

Comment: I'm surprised this wasn't the accepted answer. Very simple, and really does resolve unicode problems

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli: (1) it is  a terrible advice in general (2) It doesn't answer the question: *"How to write unicode strings into a file?"*

Comment: Is this only Python 2? Is there a Python 3.x equivalent?